# increase constrast and brightness of a grayscale image in OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

**TL;DR**: How does one increase the brightness/contrast of an image in OpenCV without having too much noise?

---

I'm a bit lost. I'd like to increase the contrast and/or brightness of a dark image so I can later parse it properly with OpenCV's canny edge detection. The thing is, I don't know how to do this without having to much noise. The camera app of my device seems quite capable when it comes to increasing brightness/contrast, OpenCV's `JavaCameraView` sadly doesn't. I've tried several things.

Such as this to increase the contrast:

```
// Built in equalizeHist function.
Imgproc.equalizeHist(image, image); // Causes a lot of noise in darker images.

// Built in Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization.
CLAHE mClahe = Imgproc.createCLAHE(cliping, new Size(8,8));
mClahe.apply(image, image); // Seems not to work in (fairly) dark images.
mClahe.collectGarbage();
```

As a last resort I also tried several things such as trying to increase the "sharpness" of the image (did not seem to help), increase the brightness (causing whitewash) and thresholding the image to binary (too much noise or whitewash prevents this from being useful). Anywho this is the code I've used to achieve the sharpening, brightening and thresholding:

```
/* Thresholding */
// Seemed somewhat promising, but too much noise.
Imgproc.threshold(processed.clone(), processed, threshold, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
// I could not figure out what the last two params were supposed to do.
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(processed, processed, threshold, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 9, 19);

/* Increasing brightness */
// Beta is added to the value of every pixel.
image.convertTo(image, image.type(), alpha, beta);

/* Increasing sharpness */
Mat blurred = new Mat();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image.clone, blurred, kernel, 0);
Core.addWeighted(image, 1.5, blurred, -1, 0, image); // Does seem to fail when the image gets too noisy.
blurred.release();
```

Directions as to how I could increase the brightness/contrast without too much noise (or how to reduce the noise afterwards without loosing too much detail) are appreciated.

Comment: When the image is really dark, naturally this means a loss of information, thus also gradient information. If you stretch the image e.g. by histogram equalisation, you will get artifacts that cannot be filtered out selectively by any algorithm. Gauss filtering is the best you can do, but of course at the cost of losing detail information and dislocation of edges.

Comment: I figured as much. Maybe I should look into how to increase the exposure time of the camera. Thanks anyways.